# What is the grammatical nature of the word "been" in perfect progressive tenses?

Tags: verbs, tenses, participles, nonfinite-verbs

The word **been** appears to be simply an auxiliary verb in all *perfect progressive* tenses (also in some *perfect tenses* with passive construction) and it is easy to see it that way. However, from a classroom perspective, it seems to confuse a lot of students because unlike other auxiliary verbs, **been** does not appear to be a *finite verb* as it is a participle form of "be".

> *They have **been** planning it for weeks.* [perfect progressive]
>
> *All the work has **been** done.* [perfect, passive construction]

Let me rephrase my question into two parts:

1. Is **been** an auxiliary verb in the example sentences quoted above?
2. If yes, is **been** the only auxiliary verb that can be *non-finite*?

Comment: "Been" is a perfect past participle as complement to auxiliary "have", progressive in your first example, and passive in the second.

Comment: @BillJ I am not sure if past participles can have "progressive" attribute.

Comment: Clauses with a perfect past participle as head occur as complement to auxiliary "have", and accept progressive and passive "be", as your examples demonstrate.

Comment: Are you clear now that "been" is an auxiliary verb in your examples? Note that all forms of "be" are auxiliary verbs, including the non-finite ones.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to answer the OP's question 1, **been** is grammatically termed as an auxiliary verb in both the example sentences provided. To answer the question 2, not only **been** but also **being** is termed as an auxiliary verb non-finite form, when it comes in a progressive passive voice sentence as ***All the work is being done***.

Always ***been*** and ***being*** are not auxiliaries, but they are non-finite forms. The verb **be** and its inflections can act as main verb in sentences.

Non-finite verb forms are ***gerunds***, ***participles*** (present/past) and ***infinitives***.

In the sentence  *I've never been to Kenya*,  **been** is the past participle form of the verb **be** meaning *visit*, and it is a non-finite, but not an auxiliary verb.

> [I started **screaming** at my parents for **trying** *to send* me to
>   camp.](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/non-finite_verbs.htm)
>
> (Screaming and trying - gerunds) (To send - infinitive verb)
>
> [**Arriving** late, I saw the other kids and they seemed **to be**
>   *excited*.](http://%20Arriving%20late,%20I%20saw%20the%20other%20kids%20and%20they%20seemed%20to%20be%20excited.%20(Arriving%20-%20present%20participle)%20(to%20be%20-%20infinitive%20verb)%20(excited%20-%20past%20participle.))
>
> (Arriving - present participle) (to be - infinitive verb) (excited -
>   past participle.)

Comment: Does that mean "been" and "being" are (the only two)  exceptions to the general acceptance that all auxiliary verbs are always finite?

Comment: @PrasadShrivatsa "Be" is always an auxiliary verb, even when it's the only verb in the sentence.